# Docusign: Obtaining Access Token?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the sample code provided by DocuSign in the Github project "qs-01-node-embed-signing-ceremony-master". That code requires me to obtain an access token.  It says to visit:

https://developers.hqtest.tst/oauth-token-generator

...in order to obtain the token. However, that page cannot be reached. It says

> This site can’t be reached.
>   developers.hqtest.tst’s server IP address could not be found.

Is there an alternative way to obtain a Docusign access token?

Note: I've had a ticket open on Docusign support since July 11th. The Docusign help docs direct me to click buttons which appear not to exist in my Docusign account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The readme link should be https://developers.docusign.com/oauth-token-generator

I will have the readme fixed. I apologize for the error.

### Added: Logging in to use the token generator

The login for the Token Generator must be a login for the Developer Sandbox. In other words, login via https://demo.docusign.net

If you can login there, then you will be able to use the Token Generator. If you can't login there, you can [sign up for a free account](https://go.docusign.com/o/sandbox/).

I have filed internal DocuSign ticket DEVDOCS-1174

Comment: I signed into Docusign using my username and password. I then pasted in the link you provided and clicked the "Get My Access Token" button, It asked me to log in again. I entered the exact same username and password, and it gave me an "Invalid email and / or password" message. I tried this on two different browsers. What is the correct way to fix this?

Comment: I suspect you're using your login for the production systems. You need to use your login for the Developer Sandbox. Please see my updated answer